# How to slow down CCMoveTo?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have `CCMoveTo` action on sprite, which is moving it from one point to another. When user hits a button the sprite should slow down with ease and continue moving to target location with new speed. I have no clue how to make this happen.

Update. Actually I replaced `CCMoveTo` with `CCMoveBy` but question still same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current implementation of `CCEaseIn/CCEaseOut` actions, you can only ease the rate of actions from and to zero. This means that if you ease `CCMoveBy/CCMoveTo` they will ease the movement speed from/to a standstill.

However, starting from cocos2d 2.1 [`CCMoveBy/CCMoveTo` are stackable](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/275). With this feature you can implement a workaround that results in the effect you want.

Setup and simulataneously run two `CCMoveBy` actions for the sprite: `actionA` will have the slower movement speed that you get after the button press. `actionB` will have the speed corresponding to the difference of the faster speed and the slower speed.

Then, when the user presses the button, you can `CCEeaseOut` `actionB` (stop `CCMoveBy`, and then launch it again with the desired `CCEaseOut`). This will look like the sprite eases from the movement speed of `actionA + actionB` to the speed of `actionA`.

---

Despite this explanation, if you are implementing game controls that you want to precisely fine tune, it might be a better idea to avoid `CCActions` and just update the sprite position frame-by-frame by implementing custom movement code.

Comment: Also have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18148993/269753 which provides another nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the EaseIn/Out action to get that effect :

```
id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(100,100)];
id ease = [CCEaseIn actionWithAction:action rate:2];
[sprite runAction: ease];
```

Taken from [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_ease)

You can find different types of easing to suit your needs .

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically change the speed of a CCMoveBy/CCMoveTo, there is a CCSpeed action you can implement.

First, when adding the CCMoveBy action, wrap it in a CCSpeed action as follows:

```
CCSpeed *action = [CCSpeed actionWithAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:myDuration position:ccp(xPos,yPos)] speed:1];
action.tag = 42;
[mySprite runAction:action];
```

Then, when you wish to modify the speed, obtain the CCSpeed action and modify it:

```
CCSpeed *action = (CCSpeed*)[mySprite getActionByTag:42];
[action setSpeed:6];
```

Comment: Didn't think about CCSpeed, this looks like a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint startPoint = ccp(10,100);
CGPoint endPoint = ccp(300,100);
float fastTime = 5.f;

CCSprite *sp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png"];
sp.position = ccp(10,100);
[self addChild:sp];
[sp runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:fastTime position:endPoint]];

//on hit
float slowTime = 10.f;
[sp stopAllActions];
float newSlowTime = ccpDistance(sp.position, endPoint)*slowTime/ccpDistance(startPoint, endPoint);
[sp runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:newSlowTime position:endPoint]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the ccmoveto action by ccactionmoveto like:

```
 CCActionMoveTo *mAction = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2f position:_selectedSpritePos];

    [_selectedSprite stopAllActions];
    [_selectedSprite runAction:mAction];
```